# Associativity Question

Tags: associativity

[image]

[image]

Can someone step by step the last line? Confused.

Comment: It looks like there is an error to me. The "$z$" term should be "$y$" instead, shouldn't it? And I think there is more than associativity being used here.

Comment: I added the previous 2 lines. What else is being used?

Comment: Well, commutativity for one.  Going from line two to line three, you should be able to quickly verify that the left-hand-sides are the same, it just changes $(x+y\times z)$ out for $(y\times z + x)$.  The right hand sides on the other hand, you can think of it first as unwrapping all of the parentheses, rearranging, and rewrapping.  $\color{blue}{x\times z}+((\color{red}{y\times z} + \color{green}{x})+\color{purple}{y}) = (\color{blue}{x\times z} + \color{green}{x})+(\color{red}{y\times z} + \underbrace{\color{purple}{y}})$.  They made the mistake of switching purple $y$ for $z$ instead.